# XPath for an element with same class names

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Can anyone help me to derive the xpath (from second div the span element label which is GP)

```html
<div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom pure-u-1-5">
            <div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-component-container ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-component-left-bordered ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom" aria-label="Visit Info" role="group"><div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-summary" aria-hidden="false">
    
        
    
</div>
<div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail" aria-label="" aria-hidden="true">
    
        <div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field">
            <span class=" " aria-hidden="true"></span>
            
                <span class=" ohp-metadata-label">Location</span>
            
            <span class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-row-value-icon  " aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class=" ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-value">Tauranga Hospital - Assmt Plan Unit TAU - </span>
        </div>
    
        
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom pure-u-1-5">
            <div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-component-container ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-component-left-bordered ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom" aria-label="GP Info" role="group"><div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-summary" aria-hidden="false">
    
        
</div>
<div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail" aria-label="" aria-hidden="true">
    
        <div class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field">
            <span class=" " aria-hidden="true"></span>
            
                <span class=" ohp-metadata-label">GP</span>
            
            <span class="ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-row-value-icon  " aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class=" ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-value">-</span>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

My XPath which i wrote it work for the first div and it return the value Location :

```
.//*[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail']/div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field']/span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label']
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath:

```
//*[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field']//span[2]
```

then you can use gettext() to get GP as a text

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//*[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail']/div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field' and span[@class=' ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-value']='-']/span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label']
```

Its result is:

> GP

Answer (score 0):

1. programmatic solution:

your xpath actually does return both elements:

[image: XPath result]

in your selenium lib you receive most likely an array and can select the second element of it

2. select the second element:

if its always the second element adding a `[2]` to the xpath helps
e.g. `"(.//*[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail'])[2]/div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field']/span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label']"`

3. by a fixed text

If you have some text in the page that is fixed, e.g. `Location` you can use that as reference and then using `ancestor` and `sibling` axes

`".//span[.='Location']//ancestor::div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail']//following-sibling::div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail']//span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label']"`

Comment: thank u for the reply and i tried the first XPath as you mentioned and i  got the NoSuchElementException (
  Message=Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-section-detail'][2]/div[@class='ohg-patient-banner-suppl-info-custom-field']/span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label'])

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my answer, should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have other unique identifiers, and the class name is used by 2 spans, this is how you can identify that span based on its index, and is the shortest way:

```
xpath:  (//span[@class=' ohp-metadata-label'])[2]
```

Now you can **scrape** the text by using selenium getText() method.
Note that we used index 2 to identify your locator, but if html code will change, and new similar spans will be added before this one, you will need to change the index.